# Flying from US through Paris to Prague

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, cdg

In November we will be arriving at CDG in Paris from the US on Delta using a US passport.  We have 1 hour 20 minutes before our flight out of CDG to Prague on Air France.  Delta says this is enough time to connect but I am concerned about passport/immigration/customs issues.  Will we have to get our luggage or will it be checked through to the flight out?  Is 1 hour 20 minutes sufficient time to connect to our flight out?

Comment: If it's on the same ticket, the luggage should be checked through to Prague (Just remember you need to go through the Green not Blue lane when you arrive in Prague - but they never check). You will have to clear passport control in CDG but this shouldn't be too long since you are connecting. Generally the passport control queues for connecting are a lot shorter. The bigger problem is if your outbound flight is late, your luggage might not arrive when you do in Prague if it's a tight connection.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  The tight connection with my international travel experience was concerning but Delta has assured me it will be okay.

Comment: I've done shorter connections at CDG. You should be fine unless your flight is late more than 30 minutes.

Comment: Delta tells me the required minimum at CDG connecting from the US is 75 minutes and my flights give me 80 minutes if all goes as planned.  No time to loiter in CDG.